# How am I able to connect Types with Parse

Tags: typescript, back4app

I'm trying to use Parse from [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com/) but I don't understand how can I use @types/parse with it. After the `npm install --save-dev @types/parse` nothing happens.

May be I have to import something somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure those are the right type definitions? [The readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/parse) says `@types/parse` are types for Parse by [parseplatform.org](https://parseplatform.org/), that looks to be a different product than Parse by Back4App. I'm not familiar with either one though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is still relevant. I've double-checked everything and found out that I use package Parse-Javascript-SDK. I've installed all @type/parse but nothing works :/

Comment: What's exactly not working and what you expected to happen after installing the package?